# JavaScript no funciona en la respuesta de un AJAX, Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax

tengo un listado de productos que relleno a través de AJAX y de la base de datos. Construyo el HTML en el controlador con php y me lo imprime con la respuesta de AJAX en un div. Bien, siempre utilizo para eliminar un producto AJAX también. Lo que pasa que no consigo que me lo detecte, no se si es porque el HTML lo construyo con la respuesta de AJAX.

No pongo todo la función del controlador ya que es muy larga. Pero devuelvo el enlace para eliminar el producto así:

```
$filtradorHtml .= " 
  </div>
     <div class=\"posicionPapelera\" id=\"posicionPapelera\">
       <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=\"$pro->id\" class=\"borrar_producto\"><i class=\"far fa-trash-alt eyeProduct\"></i></a>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Luego en la vista tengo el ajax, pero de momento para ver si funciona he puesto un alert:

```
<script>
  $(function()
{
  $(".borrar_producto").click(function()
  {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  });
});
</script>
```

Pero no da señales de nada, no hace ninguna acción. Alguien sabe por que puede ser???

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien lo he resuelto así:

```
<script>
  $(function()
{
  $(document).on('click', '.borrar_producto', function()
  {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  });
});
</script>
```